# OpenSSH Server – problems trying to connect two laptops on home network

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, timeout

This question is relating to OpenSSH client and server (which became bundled with the Windows OS rather recently).

I am hoping to get some help from someone who is more knowledgeable about SSH.

I have two laptops which both have the client OpenSSH (which now comes default with Windows 10).

One also has the Windows 10 default OpenSSH Server installed.

However,  I'm having trouble ssh'ing from the one with just the client into the one with the server.

While I can ping my "server" laptop from my "client" laptop", as both devices are at home using my home network,  when I try to ssh to my "server" laptop IP, I get an error:

```
connect to host xxxxx port 22: Connection timed out.
```

Since I'm just starting to use these features on these machines (and haven't made successful ssh connections with either of them before),  I'm not sure whether the client or the server is having a problem.  But I'm looking at the "server" laptop first.

One thing I'd like to know is how to find out what port my OpenSSH Server service is listening on... just in case it's not listening on port 22 for some reason. There is a firewall rule listed for OpenSSH Server in "Control Panel" → "System and Security" → "Windows Defender Firewall" → "Allowed Apps",  but it doesn't mention the port.  Also, my OpenSSH service IS running in `services.msc`.

I've also noted that I have a `sshd_config_default` file, but there was no actual `sshd_config` file created. The default file was all commented out.

So I wanted to ask

1. Where to verify if my OpenSSH Server service is listening for connections on port 22.
2. If anyone has a recommendation for what setting commands to use in a sshd_config file on the server laptop, which should just be connected to by another laptop in the same network.  I assume one of the settings should specify port 2,  but I'm not sure whether using these commented-out commands in the default file are the best ones to use for my setup:

   ```
   #Port 22
   #AddressFamily any
   #ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
   #ListenAddress ::
   ```
3. Any other suggestions anyone has for why the connection times out.

Comment: Good question. What I would do is to use `nmap` scanner to verify that server indeed is listening on port 22. From the client I would connect to a known good SSH server to see if that works. On server I also would connect from server to iteslf (by localhost) to see if it is working.

Comment: Can you `ssh` to `localhost:22` on each machine?

Comment: Also `resmon` in run, network tab, listening ports - This will show you all the ports that the machine is listening on, along with the executable that is listening.

Comment: ETA: Thanks for your assistance. Resmon told me my server ssh was listening on port 22. I can also login to the localhost on the server laptop. Just wanted to ask another question, in case it is related. Is it at all relevant to this connection timeout issue, that I can ping my server laptop's public IPv4, but not its local IP, from the client laptop?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Deleted my last comment,  because it is something for me to bring up with support, not you :-), I'm sorry. Thank you, I took your advice and emailed support about merging the accounts!

Answer (score 0):

Here are my answers:

1. Where to verify if my OpenSSH Server service is listening for connections on port 22.

   Run this command in your windows assuming your ssh is running on port 22 (default).

   `netstat -an|find "LISTEN"|find ":22"`
2. Any suggestion how to configure.

   As you said parameter `Port 22` in `sshd_config` file indicates the port SSH daemon should open when is started. I guess is the default if you specify none. Since this is openSSH verify [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/sshd_config) site for more info about the parameters you can use.
3. Any other suggestions anyone has for why the connection times out.

   If you can ping the nodes from each other the most common reason for the `timeout` is a firewall in between.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this time this IS a real answer.  (And it is going to be a long form of Manuel Florian's answer Part III, since it WAS a firewall issue. - thanks Manuel!)

As I mentioned before, boxes couldn't ping each other's private IPs, and then I found out both machines had the same PUBLIC IP.

Two things I did to help with this which I performed both tasks on both machines):

Step 1) I changed my machines to treat my home network as private.

These PowerShell instructions from NiklasE rtlhm at

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/change-my-network-to-private-in-windows-10/45659a7b-89ee-42c4-910f-6ffbdd31ee0a?page=2

were quick and easy to follow:

- Open Windows PowerShell in admin mode. Start -> PowerShell -> Right-click -> open as administrator
- *Get current profiles. Make sure you are logged on to the network you want to change.* 
  Get-NetConnectionProfile
- *Change the network in your list to be private*
  Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "MYWIFINETWORK" -NetworkCategory Private
- *Check that everything went fine*
  Get-NetConnectionProfile

I also changed the Firewall settings using these steps from https://kb.iu.edu/d/aopy:

1. Search for Windows Firewall, and click to open it.
2. Click Advanced Settings on the left.
3. From the left pane of the resulting window, click Inbound Rules.
4. In the right pane, find the rules titled File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - 
   ICMPv4-In).
5. Right-click each rule and choose Enable Rule.

*.... with the added step* of changing one of the rules, which had a Profile of both Public and Private, to apply *only* to Private Profiles, since I don't want anyone on an actual public network to ssh to me.

Right click on the rule,  select Properties,  Advanced Tab,  under Profiles section, uncheck Public.

After making these changes, I verified that I could ping the server from the client, I am able to ssh from my "client" to my "server" ssh device.

[SIDE NOTE on security: Of course, if anyone is reading this and wants to try it,  do so at your own risk, since calling a network "Private" means "I trust the other devices on this network - and that no one has hacked into my network".  But if you only do step 2 (without limiting the rule to private networks),  that means when you're on a public network, other devices can ping you. I'm thinking of undoing these changes when I don't need them,  may also disable SSH on both machines while not needed.]

I'll have to wait until my profile is able to be merged with user987957 to mark anything down as an answer.  However, thanks you all for your clues to help me research this problem!